# How to break these long C++ lines in a neat way?

Tags: c++, coding-style, code-formatting

I'm on my first bigger C++ project and find that I have some really long lines. My goal is to break them to 79 columns, but I do not really know how to do this in a neat way. Are there some guidelines to break lines like these:

```
VectorHistogram::VectorHistogram(size_t bins, size_t cache) : bins(std::vector<double>(bins)), cache(std::min(cache, MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES)) {
```

or

```
VectorHistogram position_histogram {settings.position_hist_bins, settings.time_sites * settings.iterations};
```

or

```
MetropolisDriver::MetropolisDriver(Settings settings) : settings(settings), system(HarmonicOscillator {settings.time_step, settings.mass, settings.mu_squared}), trajectory(ListQuantity {settings.time_sites}), ma(MetropolisAlgorithm {trajectory, system, settings.position_seed, settings.accept_seed}) {
```

Comment: What does the IDE suggest?

Comment: I can only second MichaelT: Let an automatic formatting tool decide.

Comment: #1: This 80-column limit convention thing is ancient and is designed for ancient monitors; given modern monitors and IDEs, 80 columns just doesn't quite fit enough on one line.  #2: Whatever number of columns you decide on, double-indent consecutive sublines.  That is, if you have a really long if statement and have to break it up, double-indent every subline of that if statement except for the first, don't indent the curly brace on the next line, and single-indent what's inside the curly braces.

Comment: @MichaelT I do not have an IDE, I use Vim. With `gqq`, it wraps it only on spaces that are already there, which is not really a big help.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Given modern monitors and IDEs 80 columns still makes a lot of sense because 1) the IDEs usually have a lot of junk to the sides and 2) because you often need to compare two bits of code side-by-side. In those cases people with good sight and thus small font will fit perhaps 100 characters, but people with worse sight who need bigger font will struggle to fit even 80.

Comment: `clang-format` really is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would break them so each line is conveying a different concern such as superclass constructor invocation or an expression. This might not be 79 characters, but with modern widescreen, high resolution monitors is that truly necessary anymore?

Whenever possible, let the IDE format it for you. Some are better at this than others: for example, I have found that Eclipse likes to break expressions in weird places. Sometimes (rarely) I need to resort to manual formatting, and I try to break code the way I described above.

Anyway, here is how I would format the code in your question:

```
VectorHistogram::VectorHistogram(size_t bins, size_t cache)
    : bins(std::vector<double>(bins)),
      cache(std::min(cache, MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES)) {

VectorHistogram position_histogram {
  settings.position_hist_bins, settings.time_sites * settings.iterations
};

MetropolisDriver::MetropolisDriver(Settings settings)
    : settings(settings),
      system(HarmonicOscillator {settings.time_step, settings.mass, settings.mu_squared}),
      trajectory(ListQuantity {settings.time_sites}),
      ma(MetropolisAlgorithm {trajectory, system, settings.position_seed, settings.accept_seed}) {
```

Comment: +1 for `conveying a different concern`. A small point of contention I have is that not everyone views code on hi-res, wide-screen monitors, so line widths are still a concern. I often run into annoying wrap-around issues when: posting code to/reading it on web forums/pages, pasting code snippets into word documents, printing code, looking at code on smaller devices (netbooks, smartphones/tables, etc.)

Comment: @paul In addition to this, people naturally scan top-to-bottom so beyond a certain width you're more likely to miss something at first glance.

Comment: I agree that line breaking is important and that it should be done in a way that makes logical sense based on the code being formatted. My contention is that 79 or 80 characters is too short with modern displays capable of much more and modern languages being more verbose than COBOL (which was designed for specific width lines) or old-school C (which was ridiculously terse). I am honestly not sure how long is too long: I agree that the human eye has difficulty with wide lines, this is the same reason why newspapers and magazines use multiple columns.

Comment: I have a 12.5" laptop which is 1366×768. With 80 cols, I can have a terminal and a Vim next to each other, each fitting 80 or 81 cols. So 80 is just right.

Comment: @JohnGaughan I've heard that 480px is a good width for content on screen (on regular monitors -- though w/ different screens having different ppi it's kinda moot). Your re-formatted version of the code on this page is maxed at 660px and the longest line has 99 chars; this seems like a visually pleasing max to me on 21"@1920x1080 (though I might be biased: the company where I work has a line limit standard of 100 chars for source code)

Comment: @paul the longest lines in the code I reformatted actually make me a little uneasy, they are too long. However, I was unable to find a suitable way to break them further in the time I allotted to answering this question.

Comment: @JohnGaughan If by "modern" you mean "manifestly-typed, object-oriented and used in enterprise software", sure. If you *really* mean *modern*, then I'd argue Standard ML, Ocaml, Haskell, F# and Scala are very concise and 79 characters is generally enough there.